# Transfer .properties files from server to client in web application

Tags: java, java-web-start, file-transfer

I am developing web start java application. I need some initial setup files which needs to be transfered from server to client pc and are in .properties file format. I need these files before launching my application. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using JNLP? it does not need to download on client

Comment: Yes I am using JNLP. And yes I am not downloading client jar file but I need certain properties files on client machine which will be needed to run application. So I need to transfer them first.

Comment: As i know Jar image is reflects on client and you can load any type of properties when it starts executing. But till than if you want to download a .properties file on client machine you can use FTP for that.

Comment: *"..are in .properties file format."* Do you control the code that loads the properties?